# Older book: similar to Avatar with tribal plot

Tags: story-identification, novel, psychic, dreams

Older book  title is something like "tribe of" or " people of" with a pre-colonial name after that. I can't remember more details probably written in the '80's.

A man crashes his car wakes up among hidden tribe (perhaps in an alternate dimension or post death illusion) nursing him back to health, they put people in small holes or room in the ground isolated from others. During his rehabilitation he starts to know them and lusts after a particular woman and rapes her. After a tribunal, they are sentenced to spend time in these earthen chambers, hole in the ground almost like sensory deprivation/reflection time akin to a sweat lodge but more cocoon like evoking dream time. The people have no sense of punishment in their culture, discord is the personal responsibility of each individual.

Answer (score 5):

The book is *[The Kin of Ata are Waiting for You](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/177406.The_Kin_of_Ata_Are_Waiting_for_You)* by Dorothy Bryant 1971; can't wait to read it to see how many more inaccurate details are in my post.

> Part love story, part utopian fantasy, part spiritual fable, The Kin of Ata Are Waiting for You is "a beautiful, symbolic journey of the soul" (Berkeley Monthly). Into the world of the Ata comes a desperate man, running from a fast life of fame and fortune, drugs and crime. He is led by the kin of Ata on a spiritual journey that, sooner or later, we all must take.

Comment: It's great that you figured it out!  Please come back when you've re-read it and fill in the details that matched as well as what you mis-remembered.

Answer (score 2):

Enough does not match that I'm skeptical that this is the right answer, but *[People of the Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3974515-people-of-the-sky)* by Claire Bell was released in 1989 and has someone crashing their vehicle and being rescued by a tribe descended from Native Americans and nursed back to health, and some reviews note that the plotline is similar to *Avatar*. However, it's a female who crashes, it's a crash-landing that doesn't knock her unconscious, and it's an airplane, not a car. I've requested a copy of the book from the library on the off chance it's correct.